# How can I connect to a crashed openshift container/pod

Tags: mysql, crash, openshift

My openshift database crashed and now the mysql application isn't starting up anymore. The container tries now to create a pod in a loop. But every time it fails with a login problem:

- Version: '5.7.16'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 0  MySQL
  Community Server (GPL)
- 2018-01-06T11:02:10.843097Z 2 [Note] Access
  denied for user 'UNKNOWN_USER'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
  ---> 11:02:10     MySQL started successfully
  ---> 11:02:10     Setting passwords ...
- 2018-01-06T11:02:10.864906Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
  password: NO)

durring instalation I've set a root password value with MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, but when connecting to mysql -u root I was not ask for a password. So I'm not sure what kind of password the configuration is using.

I've allready tried to reset passwords over the environment values with no effect.

Is there a way to connect to the mysql configuration even if the container isn't running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `oc debug` against the deployment configuration. This will start up the pod for the instance, but not actually start the database, instead leaving you with a command prompt for the shell in the running container. Make sure you scale down the existing instance to 0 replicas first using `oc scale`. This is necessary in case of using a persistent volume of type `ReadWriteOnce`. Once you have fixed anything, exit shell and then scale back to 1 replica.

Note that the environment variables only define what passwords are set when first started up, after that their values don't matter, but do record what was used. If you have overwritten the environment variables in the deployment config, then you have lost that record of what was used, but the password expected by the database will not have changed.

Also, inside of the database container, being able to connect to the database without needing a password is I think normal for MySQL as it will default in that case to using the local UNIX listener socket. Connection from outside of the pod still should require a password.